# Memory needed for an item in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, memory

I have learning python for a year.  In the lecture slides, I see that the compiler usually allocate 4 bytes to store items in a list.

Why can't the compiler allocate memory dynamically?  For example, if I have a small value, why don't the compiler just assign 1 or 2 bytes to store it, would it be more memory efficient?

Comment: Internally, a CPython `list` uses an array of pointers to store references to each item. Those pointers occupy 4 bytes = 32 bits on a 32 bit machine and 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine. The items themselves will occupy various amounts of RAM which is _not_ reported when you call `sys.getsizeof` on the `list`.

Comment: I don't know where you got this impression. Fundamentally, lists and arrays are very different data structures, and you shouldn't mix them up. Primitive arrays are sized, and they can and do use widely varying sizes for their elements. E.g, just with numbers, you can have 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit ints. In CPython, lists are implemented as dynamic arrays of Py_Object pointers. Each pointer takes up a machine word usually, so 8 bytes on a 64bit system, 4bytes on a 32 bit system. But that doesn't account for the memory of the Python object, which could be arbitrarily large...

Answer (score 0):

What is mean by 32 bit-integer where one bit is a sign bit and 31 bits represent number? One byte is equal to 8 bits and an integer is 32 bits, so why would they  represent it with  8 bytes where they waste 4 bytes btw in some computers you see 64-bit , they can use 8 bytes and it has only effect how greater number you can represent. The more bits ==> the more greater number.It simply goes about your processor and it's registers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that elements in a list or array take 4 bytes.

In languages with strong static types (that is, in which you have to declare the type of a variable before using it), an array takes exactly the size of the array times the size of each variable of that type. In C, char types usually uses one byte, and int types use an amount of bytes that depends on the system's architecture.

In languages with dynamic types, like Python, all variables are implemented as objects containing pointers (to a location in memory where data is actually stored) and labels (indicating the type of the variable, which will be used in runtime to determine the variable's behavior when performing operations).

The 4-byte issue probably refers to the fact that many architectures use 4 bytes for integers, but this is coincidental and it is a stretch to consider it a rule.

Comment: it is true and it depends on processor you are using . With 64-bit processor you have ability to deal with 2*32 bit integers it's because you can think of registers having 64 place.

Comment: It is not true in the sense that it does not generalize to most programming languages or processors, as it was implied by the question. As I said, it can be true in particular cases, but not in most languages.

Comment: Well, can you tell me one imperative language where the limit is not bounded?

Comment: I am not sure we are talking about the same thing...?

In C, if we have an array of char, each item in the array will take one byte. And, as noted by  juanpa.arrivillaga's comment above, arrays and lists should not be confused; lists can be implemented by arrays of pointers, which means each item will take the size of a pointer in the list, plus the size of its arbitrary representation in memory.

Comment: I think he was talking about maximum limit and in C you also can't go up 32 bits :-)

Comment: Of course you can in C, as long as you have the address space. It isn't depdent on the language, and I don't think that's what the OP was asking anyway